Не удается поменять путь установщика в SSMS
проблема заключается в том, что путь при установке Sql Server Managment Studio фиксированный, путь указанный на скрине - это путь ранней дислокации SSMS, на данный момент этот диск не используется и не подключен к ПК:

Кнопки "Изменить" или какой-либо другой в установщике нет. Я перепробовал разные варианты, удалял остатки кэша, удалял данные из реестра, с помощью программы удалил все файлы связанные с SSMS, но проблема так и не решилась.

Попробуйте переустановить на английском языке)

@Faraday не-а. В логах пишет вот такую ошибку: Install path 'E:\SSMS' seems to be on a non-existing root 'E:'

Я нашел вариант решения. Если у кого-то такое будет, то найдите в реестре (вызовите "Выполнить" (Win + R) и введите: regedit):
Для 64x OS:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Для 86x OS:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Удалите, и попробуйте перустановить.
нашел решение на англоязычном stackoverflow.
